# Get Store Details by Root Category Id

Tags: magento-1.9, category, programmatically, store-id

I am working on script and i have only Root Category Id of store. I want to get Store Details by Root Category Id.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
    $rootRategoryId = 2; 
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('core/store_group_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('root_category_id',$rootRategoryId);  
    foreach($collection as $store){
       $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store->getDefaultStoreId());
        print_r($store->getData()); 
    }
```

Comment: it is working fine